# remove image without ID from div with ID

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have the following html:

```
<div id="container"><img src="some/path/image.jpg" /></div>
```

I want to remove that image by using a function. However, i'm not very experienced with javascript and I can't get it done because the image element has no ID or class.

```
  $("button").click(function () {
      $("container").remove("container > img");
    });
```

However obviously that doesn't work. Please help!

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

Answer (score 7):

```
$("#container").find("img").remove();
```

that should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is perfect. However instead of just using the container, You should use # before it.

$("#container > img")

Answer (score 1):

$("container") should be  $("#container").

I would suggest  $("#container").empty()

Answer (score -1):

try this, could works...

```
 $("button").click(function () {
```

//get the images

```
var myImages = $('#container').find('img');

for (var i =0; i< myImages.length; i++){
//remove each image
$('#container').removeChild(myImages[i]);
}



        });
```

Comment: There is no need to iterate through the collection and remove each image. call .remove() will remove all elements matched by the selector.